# Taking forever and stuck tensorflow installation: Anaconda navigator

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda, miniconda

I am totally new to Anaconda. I go to 'uninstalled' page of anaconda navigator and search for tensorflow. I find it, click it and press apply button to install it. **A pop up comes which says 'solving packet specifications' and it just stays like that.** I do not know what to do.

I did that **'conda create -n tf tensorflow' stuff but it rather created a new environment rather than tensorflow being installed in the base environment.** If I open Jupyter from this new environment, I am, obviously, forced to install every small library like matplotlib,etc.

So, I am back to the method of going to 'uninstalled' page in the 'base' environment and trying to install tensorflow from here but the abovementioned problem comes up. **I am stuck in this loop.** Please anyone suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'solving packet specifications'` means its installing `tensorflow` package using Anaconda which may take a little time.

We need to create virtual environment to install the TensorFlow and to use as it has specific set of libraries to be installed in that environment which supports installed TensorFlow version.

Follow below code to install TensorFlow in virtual environment:

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow  #Create a Virtual environment(tf).
conda activate tf              #Activate the Virtualenv environment
pip install tensorflow         #install TensorFlow in it.
```

**Note:** You need to activate the Virtual environment each time you want to use TensorFlow.

Yes, you need to install other required package further based on your program need.

For that you can select the virtual environment and select particular non-installed package to install
Or you can use `!pip install <package-name>` in jupyter notebook.

Comment: On the last line, why pip install tensorflow instead of conda install tensorflow? Last I read, the conda installation is more optimized than pip.

Comment: Yes, agree. We can use `conda install tensorflow` also to install the `tensorflow`.